# Element not found error in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

HTML Code :

```
 <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">  
    <tr class="messageStackError">
    <td class="messageStackError">
    <img src="images/icons/error.gif" border="0" alt="Error" title=" Error  "/>&nbsp;
    Error: Invalid administrator login attempt.</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Selenium Code :

```
String message =driver.findElement(By.className("messageStackError")).getText();
```

I am getting the run time error in Selenium webdriver

> Unable to locate element: .messageStackError (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this is the timing issue, when you're going to find it would not be present at that time on `DOM`, so you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until this element could be present as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("messageStackError")));
el.getText()
```

**Note** :- Make sure before finding the element that it is not inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is inside then you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding element as `driver.switchTo().frame("frame id or name");`

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this with the help of **exception handling** and **infinite loop**:

Here's the code in python -

```
while 1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("class-name")
        break
    except:
        continue
```

If there is no exception then the loop will break or else if there's any exception like the element is not found, then the loop will be continued till the element is founded.

Answer (score 0):

The element was not loaded in the DOM by the time you requested the text from it.

To delay it you can use

```
time.sleep(x) 
# x is in seconds
```

in Python,
this will let the element load in the DOM.

For more info you can refer to this

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html